Angular component class selector not matching elements with dynamically added class name
I'm trying to dynamically render SVG elements in a loop in an Angular template. Where I use the ol.type to select the correct SVG component to render:
      <g
        *ngFor="let ol of obstacleLocations"  [attr.transform]="obstacleLocationTransform(ol)"
      >
        <g [attr.class]="ol.type"></g>
      </g>

An example of a component with a class selector:
@Component({
  selector: '.wingedsinglejump',
  template: `
    <svg
      width="100px"
      height="4px"
      viewBox="0 0 100 4"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    >
      <defs>
        <g
          id="WingedSingleJump"
          style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 1.5; stroke-linecap: round"
        >
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="24" height="4" style="fill: lightgrey" />
          <line x1="24" y1="2" x2="78" y2="2" />
          <rect x="72" y="0" width="24" height="4" style="fill: lightgrey" />
        </g>
      </defs>
      <use href="#WingedSingleJump" transform="translate(-50 -2)" />
    </svg>
  `,
})
export class WingedSingleJumpComponent { }

The component is not rendered even though the generated SVG does contain a class name that matches the selector:
<g _ngcontent-ng-c2812641055="" transform="...">
  <g _ngcontent-ng-c2812641055="" class="wingedsinglejump"></g>
</g>

However, if I hard code the class name in the template as a test:
      <g
        *ngFor="let ol of obstacleLocations"  [attr.transform]="obstacleLocationTransform(ol)"
      >
        <g class="wingedsinglejump"></g>
      </g>

The component is correctly rendered:
<g _ngcontent-ng-c2812641055="" transform="..." >
  <g _ngcontent-ng-c2812641055="" class="wingedsinglejump">
    <svg width="100px" height="4px" viewBox="0 0 100 4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><g id="WingedSingleJump" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 1.5; stroke-linecap: round;"><rect x="0" y="0" width="24" height="4" style="fill: lightgrey;"></rect><line x1="24" y1="2" x2="78" y2="2"></line><rect x="72" y="0" width="24" height="4" style="fill: lightgrey;"></rect></g></defs><use href="#WingedSingleJump" transform="translate(-50 -2)"></use></svg>
  </g>
</g>

Update:
obstacleLocations is a list of { transform: string, type: ObstacleType }
ObstacleType = 'wingedsinglejump' | 'wingeddoublejump' | 'singlejump', ... for 20 different component names.
I am hoping to use ol.type as a way to select which SVG component to render at each ol.transform location without using a series of *ngIf tests:
<g *ngIf="ol.type === 'wingedsinglejump'" class="wingedsinglejump"/>
<g *ngIf="ol.type === 'wingeddoublejump'" class="wingeddoublejump"/>
...

I also tried creating a generic component using ngComponentOutlet that took ol.type as an Input() and it would render the correct component however it would generate an invalid SVG element: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10404
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

components cannot be rendered by dynamically adding a class using ngClass instead you have to use ngIf to conditionally render them with or without the class.
  <g *ngFor="let ol of obstacleLocations">
    <g class="wingedsinglejump" *ngIf="ol.type === 'wingedsinglejump'"></g>
    <g *ngIf="ol.type !== 'wingedsinglejump'"></g>
  </g>


A better approach is to use ng-template for repeating HTML, below i an example using *ngIf with then and else logic to conditionally show the SVGs
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <svg
      width="100px"
      height="15px"
      viewBox="0 0 100 15"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <g
        *ngFor="let ol of obstacleLocations"
      >
        <g *ngIf="ol.type;then ref else null"></g>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <ng-template #ref>
    <svg
      width="100px"
      height="4px"
      viewBox="0 0 100 4"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    >
      <defs>
        <g
          id="WingedSingleJump"
          style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 1.5; stroke-linecap: round"
        >
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="24" height="4" style="fill: lightgrey" />
          <line x1="24" y1="2" x2="78" y2="2" />
          <rect x="72" y="0" width="24" height="4" style="fill: lightgrey" />
        </g>
      </defs>
      <use href="#WingedSingleJump" transform="translate(-50 -2)" />
    </svg>
  </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  obstacleLocations = [
    { type: false },
    { type: true },
    { type: false },
    { type: true },
  ];
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks Naren that will definitely work. I was trying to avoid a series of *ngIf tests for each possible value of ol.type. My original question wasn't as clear as it should have been. I've added an update.
